# User-Defined Functions and Learning to Think Like a Computer Scientist with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-defined-functions

I am brand new to coding / programming and am starting with the foundations of Python. I've used a few different resources (Codecademy, Automate the Boring Stuff, and most recently, How to Think Like a Computer Scientist by Using Python).

So far my education has been good, albeit a bit slow to start (not used to thinking in computer terms quite yet!). But I've run into a problem with one of the lessons that I cannot replicate in my IDE. Please see the code below:

```
def printTwice(bruce):
    print('bruce')
    print('bruce')
```

The lesson states the output should be 'Bruce, Bruce' which makes sense logically. However, when I go to run the code I get the following:

===RESTART: /Users/owner/Documents/bruce.py======

> > > 

So essentially just another line to start a new code from. I am writing this code in a new file and just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: You most likely aren't ever calling the function.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the replies. Again, brand new to coding so what exactly do you mean by saying "how are you running your code" ?

Comment: Below where you define your function you need to call the function with `printTwice()`, also you can probably get rid of the `bryce` in parantheses when defining the function as it currently is not needed

Comment: @professor_joykill thanks for the insight. Apologies for my newbish questions, but can you show me what you mean by calling the function below where I'm defining it? I did not include the final command 'print bruce, bruce). For example .                                                                   
'def printTwice(bruce):
print bruce, bruce'

Comment: Ok I figured it out thanks to all your help! I added printTwice() at the end of the function which I understand in this case is essentially "taking the place of" the normal print function because of what I defined printTwice as up above. Thank you all! First question on this community and you guys are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `printTwice('bruce')` on a new line after the function, with no indentation like so:

```
def printTwice(bruce):
    print('bruce')
    print('bruce')

printTwice('bruce')
```

This line will call your `printTwice` function, passing the value `'bruce'` to the variable `bruce`, which is not used.

Comment: Thank you, Milk! Very helpful!